# What happens when new ClassName() is called..?

Tags: java, object

I know that in simple words an Object is created. But i will better make it clear it with a scenario,

```
class A {
    public A(String path){
    }
}

class AB extends A{
    public AB(String path){
      super(path);
    }
}

class B{
    public void foo(){
        AB a = new AB("myPath");
        // now will constructor of class AB will run on another instance of 
        // AB or is there any other way "a" constructed.    
    }
}
```

I'm asking this because if constructor runs on another instance (in this case AB), then who will give it the String path required (and after all no default constructor is allowed here.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "another instance" in this code; there's just the one.

`new AB("myPath")` calls `public AB(String path)` which in turn calls `public A(String path)`, all on the same instance.

An instance of `AB` [is-an](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) instance of `A`, which in turn [is-an](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) instance of `Object`.

Comment: This is because the instance of AB **is** also an instance of A since an AB is an A (via the extends).

Comment: @aix.. what i mean to ask is where does public AB(String path) run on... may be it needs an Object to run too...?

Answer (score 1):

The constructor will "run on" a newly created instance of AB. A reference to this instance is returned by the `new` expression and stored as value of `a`